# Common page width?

Tags: css

I just made a new wordpress theme for a code type site, I am currently at 920px wide, I am curious what most people are using for a width now days, I would like to go wider but I just want to know if there is any kind of standard or common width that most people use?

Comment: Not a WordPress question, try http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A width of 950-960px should be ok for most screen resolutions. Css Frameworks/Libraries like blueprint, 960gs, etc. use the same width.

Comment: Agree with Kaiser. 960 is good because it's divisible by a lot of numbers. This makes it easy to create different configurations of columns with recognizable widths.

Comment: @Brian Fegter Blueprint uses 950 because it doesn't need a gap after the last column.

Comment: Cool. Didn't know that.